# What happened to Old Earth in the Dune saga?

Tags: dune

There are several passages from the Dune series that hint that either Earth was forgotten and likely destroyed.

The God-Emperor of Dune, Leto II, uses his genetic memory to recall ancient knowledge of Earth on two occasions.

This passage from *Children of Dune* could be interpreted to imply either it was no longer in human memory, (i.e. - forgotten) or that Earth ceased to exist.

> It gave him a sense of timeless buoyancy to know that few in his universe would recall Chaucer or know any London except the village on Gansireed. St. Thomas was preserved in the Orange Catholic Bible and Azhar Book, but Canterbury was gone from the memories of men, **as was the planet which had known it**.

In this passage from *God-Emperor of Dune*, Leto II, remembers back to the time of distant human ancestor long ago, presumably on Earth.

> This morning I was born in a yurt on the edge of horse-plain **in a land of a planet which no longer exists**.

And in *Chapterhouse Dune*, a Bene Gesserit reverend mother Odrade refers to an ancestral planet that no longer exists. She says this shortly after speaking of Old Earth and mentions that multiple planets no longer exist.

> "Each planet has its own character where we draw patterns of Old Earth. ... Mark this place well, Miles. **Our ancestral worlds are gone**, but here we have recaptured part of our origins."

So what happened to Old Earth?

Side note: This makes me wonder if there are any world-busting weapons in the Dune series. I don't remember any such weapons.

Please answer with quotes from canon sources or extraneous writings by the authors of the Dune series. I prefer answers from Frank Herbert (true Dune canon) over all other writers (lesser canon).

Comment: Nuked into oblivion by the thinking machines, if memory serves

Comment: Do you want answers from only the original Dune works? Or from the expanded works written after Frank Herbert's death?

Comment: @HorusKol If the answer is in the original series by Frank Herbert, that would be fine. Otherwise, I would accept answers from the expanded series.

Comment: @RichS But you do know that what you call "the expanded series" contradicts the original works even worse than the Dune Encyclopedia did, right?

Comment: @MrLister Does the expanded series contradict the original works on this specific question?

Comment: @RichS I didn't know for sure (otherwise I could have written up an answer). This was just a warning that there are basically different kinds of canon.

Comment: Dune Messiah references that a "stone burner" (which causes Paul's blindness) is a world-busting weapon; that's it's only strategic purpose.  If it doesn't destroy a planet, it just causes blindness to those who have the misfortune to be near when it goes off.  It's never said that Earth was the victim of a stone burner.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the original works by Frank Herbert, Earth is simply referred to as "gone" - but there is no indication of what really happened to Earth.

Amongst the expanded Dune works of Brian Herbert and Kevin J Anderson, Earth was the location of Omnius Prime (the great artificially intelligent overmind). During the Butlerian Jihad, the rebelling humans launched a vast atomic strike against Earth to destroy Omnius Prime. The fact that it was the homeworld of the machines and also highly radioactive would have meant that humans would continue to give the place a wide berth until it was likely forgotten.

On the other hand, the Dune encyclopaedia makes mention of a planetoid (or asteroid) striking the Earth around 2800 AD, causing devastation and the movement of the Imperial seat to Ceres. However, the world was still populated at least until 19,000 AD (about 3,000 years after the Butlerian Jihad, and 7,000 years before Paul and Leto II). However, the encyclopaedia is considered an unreliable source within the Dune works themselves.

Comment: Dude, it’s *Optimus* Prime.

Comment: @PaulD. Waite, what?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Stop posting spoilers for *Transformers: Dune*

Comment: It's *Dune: Transformed.*

Comment: @HorusKol An asteroid hitting the Earth would not destroy the planet. Rearrange it? Certainly. Atomic weapons would not destroy it either. The quotes from canon sources in my question indicate the planet itself was destroyed.

Comment: Could be metaphor - an unlivable world is just as good as destroyed - and if people haven't been to that world in thousands of years, it's just as good as "gone" (refer to Asimov's work where Earth was "gone", but it turns out it was just abandoned after the Spacers turned it radioactive and everybody forgot about it).